# Find a 1-1 correspondence between N and 5N (the set of all positive multiples of 5)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I missed this day in class and my professor can't meet with me until test day if anyone could help me understand how to do this.

Comment: Try writing down $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,\dots\}$ and $5\mathbb{N} = \{0,5,10,\dots\}$; does anything come to mind?

Comment: I understand that they are bound together in in that for every natural number, N, 5 is multiplied by that number. It's like i understand what is happening, but do not know how to express it in a way in which my answer would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Such a one-to-one correspondence looks like

> \begin{align} 
> 0 &\leftrightarrow 0 \\
> 1 &\leftrightarrow 5 \\
> 2 &\leftrightarrow 10 \\
> 3 &\leftrightarrow  15\\
> &\,\,\vdots
> \end{align}

Let's try to come up with a function $f$ with that is such a bijection. We want $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=5$, $f(2)=10$, etc. This looks linear, with slope equal to 5 and y-intercept of 0. So maybe the function

$$ f(x) = 5x$$

will work. We will prove that $f$ works (ie is a 1-1 cor).

To prove $f$ is **one-to-one**, take $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$. Then if $f(x) = f(y)$, we have $5x=5y$. Dividing through by 5, we see that $x=y$.

To prove it is **onto**, take any $y \in 5\mathbb{N}$. Then set $x=y/5 \in \mathbb{N}$. This gives
$$f(x) = f(y/5) = 5(y/5) = y.$$

Comment: Thanks so much :) i didn't realize i was trying to express it as a function.